# Ternary Operator Outputting True Option when False

Tags: ruby, ternary-operator, string-interpolation

The program below outputs the lyrics of the song "99 Bottles of Beer".

When the song reaches the point where there is only 1 bottle left, it uses the singular form of "bottle". To accommodate this, I have used a ternary operator to choose the correct case at any given moment.

**However**, when the `beer_bottles` count reaches 1 in my program, the last sentence still outputs "bottles", even when it's clear the ternary operator evaluates to false.

I tested the ternary operator in IRB with `beer_bottles = 1` and it correctly outputted the false option: "bottle".

Help understanding why this occurs is greatly appreciated!!

```
beer_bottles = 99

while beer_bottles >= 2 do
  plural = "bottles"

  singular = "bottle"

  plural_or_singular = beer_bottles > 1 ? plural : singular

  puts "#{beer_bottles} #{plural_or_singular} of beer on the wall, #{beer_bottles} #{plural_or_singular} of beer."

  beer_bottles -= 1

  puts "BOTTLE COUNT: #{beer_bottles}"

  puts "Take one down and pass it around, #{beer_bottles} #{plural_or_singular} of beer on the wall."
end
```

Comment: Q: Are you sure you actually get down to "1" at that point?  Q: Should you move the ternary *AFTER* the decrement?

Comment: You stop the while loop at 2. After you subtract one, you don't recalculate `plural_or_singular`. You should move that further down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The safest thing to do is check at the moment you output the variable. You can simply move your ternary down before you print the last line.

I would be tempted to extract it into a separate method. In fact, this is what Rails does with `pluralize`. We can create our own simplified version:

```
def pluralize(count, noun)
  "#{count} #{count==1 ? noun : noun + 's'}"
end
```

Then your code might look like this:

```
99.downto(1) do |n|
  puts "#{pluralize(n, "bottle")} of beer on the wall, #{pluralize(n, "bottle")} of beer."
  puts "Take one down and pass it around, #{pluralize(n-1, "bottle")} of beer on the wall."
end
```

Comment: Ayy! Using the `.downto` and a custom method is much cleaner, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you are not calculating `plural_or_singular` again after `beer_bottles -= 1` as `beer_bottles` got updated.

Solution:

```
beer_bottles = 99

while beer_bottles >= 2 do
  plural = "bottles"

  singular = "bottle"

  plural_or_singular = beer_bottles > 1 ? plural : singular

  puts "#{beer_bottles} #{plural_or_singular} of beer on the wall, #{beer_bottles} #{plural_or_singular} of beer."

  beer_bottles -= 1
  plural_or_singular = beer_bottles > 1 ? plural : singular
  puts "BOTTLE COUNT: #{beer_bottles}"

  puts "Take one down and pass it around, #{beer_bottles} #{plural_or_singular} of beer on the wall."
end
```

Comment: The first check is now entirely unnecessary.

Comment: Ahh, yes! For some reason I assumed `plural_or_singular` was being calculated every time I interpolated it. Woops! Thanks Mark!